How to extract and use "variadic" template parameters and their types?
How could I extract and use the types defined in variable template arguments of a C++ class so that instead of defining multiple duplicates of the following class which defer by only the number and types of parameters:
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class SUTTestFixture1
{
public:
    void SetUp(T1 expected, vector<T2> data)
    {
        _expected = expected;
        _data = data;
    }

protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
    vector<T2> _data;
    T1 _expected;
};
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class SUTTestFixture2
{
public:
    void SetUp(T1 expected, T2 param, vector<T3> data)
    {
        _expected = expected;
        _param = param;
        _data = data;
    }

protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
    vector<T2> _data;
    T1 _expected;
    T2 _param;
};

I expect to be able to just use a single class with variale template arguments:
template <typename... T>
class SUTTestFixture
{
public:
    void SetUp(T... args)
    {
        _expected = args...[0];
        _data = args...[1]; // expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
    }

protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
    vector<T...> _data; // XXX
    T... _expected; // error: expected unqualified-id before ‘...’ token
};

SUTTestFixture1 use case:
class TestFixture1 : public SUTTestFixture1<long, long>, public testing::TestWithParam<tuple<long, vector<long>>>
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        RangeTestFixture1::SetUp(get<0>(GetParam()), get<1>(GetParam()));
    }
    long Function1Test()
    {
        return _sutObj.Function1(_data);
    }
};

SUTTestFixture2 use case:
class TestFixture2 : public SUTTestFixture2<size_t, size_t, size_t>, public testing::TestWithParam<tuple<size_t, size_t, vector<size_t>>>
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        RangeTestFixture2::SetUp(get<0>(GetParam()), get<1>(GetParam()), get<2>(GetParam()));
    }
    size_t Function2Test()
    {
        return _sutObj.Function2(_param, _data);
    }
};


What is T... _expected supposed to mean? Basically, T... _expected is invalid syntax.

I don't understand what this pseudocode is supposed to do. std::tuple<T...> would store all of the args... together, but I don't understand how you want to split them between _data and _expected.

vector<T...> would mean your pack can be of size 2 at most, and contain only a value and optional allocator for any of it to be valid. It would be better to take a step back and discuss what you want to accomplish, instead of the problems in your attempt to accomplish it.

I think it is unclear what is the expected output/behavior.

Updated my post to show my intent

Which of expected and/or data vary in number?

"defining multiple duplicates of the following class" please show us at least 2 of such duplicates.

auto t = std::make_tuple<T...>(args); and _expected = std::get<0>(t);

What confuses me are names _data and _expected. What if args... contains not exactly 2 arguments? If it's impossible, then your first version already looks optimal. Even it can, then you want std::tuple<T...> t;, but then you can't name the individual elements.

99% sure what you want is SUTTestFixture<std::tuple<T1s...>, std::tuple<T2s...>>, using your 2 param template, or a variation on that with only one tuple

SoA: std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> m_data;. Or AoS:  std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> m_data; and std::tuple<T...> m_expected;.

You don't need a second copy of all your values, you can just directly inherit Testing::TestWithParam
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class SUTTestFixture : public testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<R, Args...>>
{
public:
    R Expected() {
        return std::get<0>(this->GetParam());
    }
    template <typename Method>
    R Actual(Method method) {
        // Peel Expected off the front, and then call _sutObj.Method(args...)
        return std::apply([&](auto&&, auto&&... args){ 
            return std::invoke(method, _sutObj, args...); 
        }, this->GetParam());
    }
protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
};

class TestFixture1 : public SUTTestFixture<long, std::vector<long>>
{
};

class TestFixture2 : public SUTTestFixture<size_t, size_t, std::vector<size_t>>
{
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(TestFunction1, TestFixture1, testing::Combine(testing::Values(1L), testing::Values(std::vector{1L})));

TEST_P(TestFixture1, Foo) {
    EXPECT_EQ(Expected(), Actual(&SUT::Function1));
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(TestFunction2, TestFixture2, testing::Combine(testing::Values(1uz), testing::Values(1uz), testing::Values(std::vector{1uz})));

TEST_P(TestFixture2, Foo) {
    EXPECT_EQ(Expected(), Actual(&SUT::Function2));
}

As an alternative, you can define a struct for each test fixture's parameters, and not bother with std::tuples
struct TestFixture1Params
{
    long expected; 
    std::vector<long> data; 
};
class TestFixture1 : public testing::TestWithParam<TestFixture1Params>
{
public:
    long Function1Test()
    {
        return _sutObj.Function(GetParam().data);
    }
protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
};

struct TestFixture2Params
{ 
    size_t expected;
    size_t param;
    std::vector<size_t> data; 
};
class TestFixture2 : public testing::TestWithParam<TestFixture2Params>
{
public:
    size_t Function2Test()
    {
        return _sutObj.Function(GetParam().param, GetParam().data);
    }
protected:
    SUT _sutObj;
};


This is more difficult to read and maintain.

@KokHowTeh - Not at all. This is fairly idiomatic stuff, certainly not more difficult then generating the class you wanted. I suspect any "difficulty" is just familiarity bias at play.

@KokHowTeh std::tuple doesn't have names for it's elements, so if you are using it, you have to have some machinery like this. The alternative is not using std::tuple

My subclasses of SUTTestFixture the different functions of the SUT. i.e., Function1() and Function2().How does this handle that?

@KokHowTeh you construct SUTTestFixture with a pointer-to-member-function for each function

I try out the first option. However, I can't improvise on it as it has syntax errors and there are a few things unclear to me:
(1) How does TestFixture1 extract and pass the ::testing::Values defined in INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P to SUTTestFixture? What's {} /*?*/?
(2) The sample is missing TEST_P

@KokHowTeh 1) It doesn't, SUTTestFixture does it. 2) So does the question. That hasn't changed. {} /*?*/ is default constructing _sutObj, because you don't show how it is instantiated. I've edited to fix the errors, and make it work for cvref qualified methods

Error when &SUT::Function1 expects a reference to vector<T>

You have to extract the first n-1 and the last argument from your template argument list independently and then write them to independent variables.
This process would be much easier if you were to receive the vector argument first and the rest second. But as it stands you have to do some template argument list manipulation with helper types.
template <typename... Ts>
struct LastArg {};
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct LastArg<T0, T1, Ts...> : LastArg<T1,Ts...> {
};
template <typename T>
struct LastArg<T> {
  using type = T;
};

template <typename T0, typename AL>
struct PrependToList{};
template <typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct PrependToList<T0, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<T0, Ts...>;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct DropLast {};
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct DropLast<T0,T1,Ts...> {
  using type = typename PrependToList<T0, typename::DropLast<T1,Ts...>::type>::type;
};
template <typename T>
struct DropLast<T> {
  using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <typename... T>
class SUTTestFixture {
public:
    using Data = std::vector<typename LastArg<T...>::type>;
    using Expect = typename DropLast<T...>::type;

    void SetUp(Expect expect, Data data)
    {
        _expected = expect;
        _data = data;
    }
    template <typename... U>
    requires (std::is_same_v<typename DropLast<U...>::type,Expect> && std::is_same_v<typename LastArg<U...>::type, Data>)
    void SetUp(U... us) {
        SetUp(slice(std::tuple{us...}, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(us)-1>{}), std::get<sizeof...(U)-1>(std::tuple{us...}));
    }

protected:
    //SUT _sutObj;
    Data _data;
    Expect _expected;

    template <typename Tup, std::size_t... I>
    auto slice(Tup tup, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::tuple{std::get<I>(tup)...};
    }
};

Here's a demo.
